# DatePicker variable "is not used"

Tags: java, android

I have a variable I created from DatePicker, but I have an error that says that "The value of the local variable datePickerListener is not used"

I'm not sure why my code that references it isn't working correctly? I also imported  android.app.DatePickerDialog;

```
public void changeDateClickHandler(View v){

Log.d("Enter Scores", "I hear the Change Date Button");

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener;
datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yearOfYear, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        year = yearOfYear;
        month = monthOfYear;
        day = dayOfMonth;

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        Date dateOfGames = cal.getTime();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        String cs = df.format(dateOfGames);
        date.setText(cs);

    }
    };
```

}

Comment: Usually that's not an error, it's a warning.

Answer (score 0):

That warning (not an error) means exactly what it says.  You're not using that variable after you set it.  You probably want to assign it to be the listener for one particular `DatePickerDialog`, otherwise it won't listen to anything.

The listener should be used in a constructor for `DatePickerDialog`; the javadoc for the class is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html).

Comment: It is assigned to the listener.

Comment: Well, you haven't shown any code assigning it to the listener; and your compiler warning says that it isn't.

Comment: Isn't this assigning it to the listener? DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener;
datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

Comment: Nope.  That's declaring a variable and creating an object.  You haven't assigned it to be the listener for any particular `DatePickerDialog` at that point.

Comment: @user3912157 See the documentation of the [`DatePickerDialog` constructors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html); that's the place where you would use the listener.  A listener that isn't attached to anything is like a set of headphones that's just sitting on the table.

Comment: Hey, @ajb, I don't suppose you'd fancy editing that link into my answer would you?  Or I can do it, I guess.  I feel it should probably be there, for completeness.

Comment: OK, done.  Unfortunately, the `#` thingy that takes you to the actual constructor has space characters in it and the SO markdown seems to have a problem with that...